# Sending octet-stream in Http Request React Native to Custom Vision Service

Tags: react-native

I want to make a POST to the end point of custom vision service and send an image captured with camera. I have the URI of the photo from the cache and the base64 format. I tried to set the body of the request to be the base64. format provided by RNCamera option but it would respond with:

> "Bad Request Image Format, Uri: aba50242b33b4a25847fb5cb81c78619".
>   The requests accepts  'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'

```
async classifyImageFile() {
    debugger
    var baseUrl = "https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v2.0/Prediction/cfb6e5e4-57e1-4a35-8d5f-736613c6bf56/image?iterationId=f903217a-63bf-4c54-ae65-3777cdbcc5de";
    fetch(baseUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Prediction-Key': '3f85f3746d0f4e82843f9eae70e09e97'
        },
        body: new Buffer(this.state.imageFile, 'base64')
    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            console.log(responseJson)
            this.validateResponse(responseJson);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(error.code)
            console.log(error.message)
        });
}
 async takePicture() {
    if (this.camera) {
        const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
        const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options)
        this.setState({
            url: data.uri,
            imageFile: data.base64
        })
        this.classifyImageFile();
    }
};
```

Comment: I updated the post, I also tried without the Buffer, sending only the data.base64, as it is seems like byte array to me.

Comment: try `Buffer.from(this.state.imageFile,'base64')`

Comment: I just tried but it doesn't seem to work